# Material constraint in anisotropic elasticity

Tags: elasticity

Consider the 2-dimensional (plane strain) case of a linear elastic general anisotropic material. Its elasticity tensor in engineering (Voigt) notation is positive definite, and looks like:
\begin{equation}
C_{ij} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13}\\
c_{21} & c_{22} & c_{23}\\
c_{31} & c_{32} & c_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
I was wondering if the condition $c_{11}c_{33}-c_{13}^2>0$ a consequence of the positive definiteness of $C_{ij}$ or a consequence of its ellipticity? I am not even sure there exist necessary conditions for ellipticity in the general anisotropic case.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the strain energy density to be positive, the elasticity tensor has to be positive definite. According to [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), a necessary condition for positive definiteness is that all of the [principal minors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) are positive. The condition you cite follows directly from the second principal minor being positive (under an appropriate symmetry operation).